# How to make flv-players work with iphone/ipad?

Tags: flash, ipad, flv, jwplayer

i am using jw player for playing flv video on the web.
but some of my costumer saying that cant play video on their ipad,

i looked up and learn ipad dont have flash support. So how could i make video work.

Thank for everyone who interested in

Sincerly Yours
Suleyman Demirkeser

Answer (score 1):

HTML5

or

http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-streaming.html

which I think works with html5 to make it compatible with iOS